# How can I disable skype's spell checker? (windows 10 version)

Tags: windows-10, skype, spell-check

In the windows 10 configuration I already have the thwo checkboxes disabled:

[image]

Instead in Skype I still see the annoying red underline on:

[image]

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the registry below:

1.Press Windows Key + R and enter regedit. Click on OK or press Enter.

2.Once the Registry Editor starts, navigate to this key: HKEY_USERSS-1-5-21-2072414048-1790450332-1544196057-1001SoftwareMicrosoftTabletTip1.7.

3.Go to the right pane and double click EnableAutocorrection DWORD.

Next, set the Value data to 0.  The same steps can be used to enable spell checking. If this value isn’t available, create it manually.

Comment: Did you just copy & paste this from [here](https://windowsreport.com/skype-autocorrect-windows-10/) (including the missing slashes in the registry path)?